# Embed content from a different server

Tags: python, html, cgi

I have a landing page (mainly CSS and HTML) that I want to add content to. The issue is that the server that deploys the page is outdated and I'd rather run my content from another server. The content I want to add is a cgi script written in Python. Is it possible to run this script from within another server on the landing page. Ultimately, the page will load content from two different servers.

Comment: Yes it's possible - have the landing page pull the output from the second server and send it on. This won't be particularly quick, though. A better solution is to redirect from the first server to the second with a 301 response (if the second server is accessible)

Comment: How would these be implemented? Would I simply use the <object> tag and provide the url of the page?

Comment: In Python, I've no idea: sorry. In PHP you can use `readfile("http://myURL")` to retrieve and relay the output, or 'file_get_contents("http://myURL")' if you need more control.  It occurs to me that you could include an iFrame in your page with the URL of your second server. The 301 response is best done in .htaccess, but won't work if you need to mix output from both servers.